# Replacing multiple CSS files

Tags: jquery

So I want to replace 3 css files on a page, with the possibility of a 4th on certain pages... After reading around, I have this:

```
$("link").each(function(index) {
switch (index) {
    case 1: $this.attr("href","css1.css");
            break;
    case 2: $this.attr("href","css2.css");
            break;
    case 3: $this.attr("href","css3.css");
            break;
    case 4: $this.attr("href","css4.css");
            break;  
}
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I feel I am using "this" incorrectly but I really don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing the `$this` reference to the `$(this)` jQuery Object Element

```
$("link").each(function(index) {

    var $this = $(this); // dyadaaa!

    switch (index) {
        case 0: $this.attr("href","css1.css");
                break;
        case 1: $this.attr("href","css2.css");
                break;
        case 2: $this.attr("href","css3.css");
                break;
        case 3: $this.attr("href","css4.css");
                break;  
    }

});
```

The `.each()` method takes the argument index as a `zero` based value from the Elements Array collection, so you too, start with `0`

---

Just to share a secret ;) you can do it like:

```
var links = ['css1.css', 'css2.css', 'css3.css', 'css4.css'];
$('link').each(function( i ){
   $(this).attr("href", links[i]);
});
```

Or either (if your stylesheets are **really** named like that) just like:

```
$('link').each(function( i ){
   $(this).attr("href", "css"+ (i+1) +".css");
});
```

...where logically `(i+1)` instead of `0,1,2,3`  will return `1,2,3,4`

Comment: Thank you sir! Worked perfectly. Don't worry I will guard your secret with my life.

Answer (score 1):

No. you are looking for a jquery wrapper over this then you need to do `$(this)`. But here you can directly  assign to the dom element like `this.href="css1.css"`. 
Also Index is **Zero** based. so probably you need to handle case 0.

```
$("link").each(function(index) {
var $this = $(this);
switch (index) {
     case 1: $this.attr("href","css1.css");
        break;
case 2: $this.attr("href","css2.css");
        break;
case 3: $this.attr("href","css3.css");
        break;
 case 4: $this.attr("href","css4.css");
        break;  
}
});
```

You can write it as , as `this` here refers to DOM element itself and href can be accessed as a property.

```
$("link").each(function(index) {

switch (index) {
case 0: ??// Something here?
case 1: this.href ="css1.css";
        break;
case 2: this.href="css2.css";
        break;
case 3: this.href="css3.css";
        break;
 case 4: this.href="css4.css";
        break;  
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using
    $(this)
instead of
    $this